# How to map a photo onto 3D surface in PHP?

Tags: php, 3d, texture-mapping

I'm working on product customization webapp and I ran into problem how to map user uploaded images or texts onto complex 3D surfaces in my website back-end. It is easy to apply simple skew and there are libraries for that I looking for something more powerful. I have photos of my products and also corresponding 3D models of the customization surfaces (eg. female t-shirt chest part has quite complex surface if I want to show it from different angles).

It there any good tool for this kind of operation? Either on the server side (PHP) or client side (HTML5, js)...

At the moment I've run only onto [Image_3D](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_3D/), but this one doesn't allow texturing.

Comment: You can't really do this natively in PHP. It's possible to do in JavaScript but not with any current technology that is widely supported. I would recommend looking into a Flash-based solution.

Comment: +1 for the reference to such valuable resource.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar to this using pov-ray though my use case was simpler (3D book images, so my model was basically just a cuboid).

If you define your model in a pov-ray script, then when you upload the image in the back-end you can use pov-ray to render the model with that image as the texture.

http://www.povray.org/